# Migrate photos from one Facebook profile to another

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to migrate photos (albums, captions, etc.) to another Facebook profile?
Namely, from a profile to a page?

Is it also possible to keep the user comments on the migrated photos?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to do this outside of using a script or manually downloading the photos and re-uploading them to the new profile.

The comments will not be kept as the user who posted the comments would have to grant you permission to move his comments as well as other logistics (internal storage of comments at Facebook)